# Mockito fails with Pact contract tests

Tags: java, junit, mockito, pact

**Mockito ArgumentCaptor fails with JUnit5 Pact contract tests**

I found out a weird behaviour when using Pact with Mockito (JUnit5):

I'd like to get the content of `payload` in `Client.send(payload)` of the Manager class in the tests:

```java
public void send(Event event){

    var payload = new SendEvent(event);
    client.send(payload);
  }
```

So in the tests normally we can check the `Client.send(payload)` call with, what works without any problems:

```java
manager.sendEvent(foo);
verify(client).send(payload);
```

Although using `ArgumentCaptor` to get the content results in following error:

```java
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Event> captor;

@State("state")
@PactVerifyProvider("pactVerifyProvider")
public String pactEvent(){
   manager.sendEvent(foo);
   verify(client).send(captor.capture());
}


=> Verification Failed - Failed to invoke provider method '...'
```

Does anyone know if this is a known problem? Basically it is not possible to grab content when using `Pact`. The same code with only plain `Mockito` works without any flaws.

Full Stacktrace:

```java
Event
    generates a message which
    Verification Failed - Failed to invoke provider method 'sendEvent'

...


java.lang.AssertionError: Service - Generates message 'event'  
Failures:

1) Event

    1.1) Failed to invoke provider method 'sendEvent'

    at au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.PactVerificationContext.verifyInteraction(PactVerificationContext.kt:63)
    at test.ContractTest.testTemplate(ProviderContractTest.java:80) -> thats where "context.verifyInteraction();"" is used
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)

Process finished with exit code -1
```

So it seems that the ArgumentCaptors cannot be used with Pact?

EDIT: corrected ArgumentCaptor and added full stack trace

Comment: It looks like you're using an `ArgumentCaptor<String>` to try to capture a `SendEvent`. Is that right? Also, does your "Failed to invoke provider method '...'" have a "Caused by: SomeOtherException" further down in that trace that might point out where Mockito and your System-Under-Test are not cooperating?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I changed it to the correct ```ArgumentCaptor```, since this already gives an IDE hint when used wrong. Also I added the full StackTrace, but its quite short, thats why Im asking here.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution:

```java
    @State("state")
    @PactVerifyProvider("pactVerifyProvider")
    public String pactEvent(){
       manager.sendEvent(foo);
       verify(client).send(captor.capture());
}
```

`@State` needed to refer to an empty method, so set an empty state independent of the `@PactVerifyProvider`.